# how to solve arrange boxes to get the smallest height problem and which algorithm to use?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

how to solve this problem?
Given a group of boxes, it is requested to arrange these boxes on top of each other to reach the minimum possible height.
it is mandatory that a box “X” cannot be placed on top of another box “Y” unless the 2D base area of X is less than or equal to 2D base area of Y. It is allowed to rotated any box to use any two sides as its base. it must use only one instance of each box

Comment: Area or dimensions?  If area, rotate each box to have the shortest end up and sort by area.  If dimensions, what would you do with the boxes `(4,4,4)`, `(5,3,1)`, and `(6,2,2)`?

Comment: @btilly I didn't get what you mean by area or dimensions? anyway in your test case we will have these boxes and rotations (4,4,4), the second box (5,3,1) (5,1,3) (3,1,5), the third box (6,2,2) (2,2,6) so the optimal solution would be 7 => (4,4,4) then (5,3,1) then(6,2,2)

Comment: I think what @btilly is getting at is that this is a trivial problem as written, but harder if there's a restriction that A box can only go on top of another if it can be placed so its surface is contained in the surface of the box below. That's violated in the example by having the 5x3 surface on top of the 4x4 surface.

Comment: @Dave, I got it thanks a lot!, my professor gave us this test case if we have box1 (9,3,6), box2  (2,3,7), box3 (6,4,10) and the answer is   box3 with base 6*10 and height 4 then box1 with 6*9 and height  3 then box2 with base 3*7 and height 2 ..  what makes me confused is in the statement of the problem he wrote "area", and I'm in the first time thought it is similar to box stacking famous DP problem

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we can solve this using DP. I am suggesting backtracking approach.

1. Find all rotations possible of every box, maintain array of these possible rotations
2. Sort array according to their base areas
3. Process each box 1 by 1, check if it can be added on top of already added boxes.
4. When all boxes are added to stack, check if it has minimum height.
5. Backtrack to process these boxes in different way.

Also, we will need to have a set which will make sure only 1 instance of each box is added(before adding a box, check if box has been added in this iteration or not).

Link to famouse backtracking problem as you mentioned in comments:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/box-stacking-problem-dp-22/

Comment: The linked problem is harder. Here we care about area and allow equality. There they care about the dimensions separately, and don't allow equality.